# ECHO No error but not displaying data from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, echo

echo 'DESCRIPTION: '.$row['DESCRIPTION']; in the code below is not displaying at all...It runs the first statement but the second one doesn't seem to be executing. I don't understand why. I'm not getting any error which is the worse kind of error. Some help please!

PHP FILE:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE `ID` != '67' && `ID` != '68' ORDER BY SORT_ORDER ASC";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if ($result === false) { echo "An error occurred."; }
?>

<?php
//mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
//mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

      echo $_POST['book'];
      echo $_POST['chapter'];
      $book = $_POST['book'];
      $chapter = $_POST['chapter'];
      $tbl_link = "PLD_LINK";

      $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_link WHERE `TITLE` like '%$book%' && `SORT_ORD` = '%$chapter%'";
      $result1=mysql_query($sql);
      if ($result1 === false) { echo "An error occurred."; }
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){
      echo 'DESCRIPTION: '.$row['DESCRIPTION'];
      }
?>

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
{ $results[] = $rows; }
$tpl->assign('results', $results); 
?>
<?php
}
mysql_close();
unset ($username, $password, $db_name, $tbl_name);
?>
```

TPL FILE:

```
<form action="search_bible.php" method="post">
<p><select name='book'><option value="">Select Book</option></p>
{foreach item=rows from=$results}<p><option value='{$rows.TITLE}'>{$rows.TITLE}</option></p>{/foreach}
</select>
&nbsp;
<span style="font-size:12px;">Chapter<input type="text" name="chapter" value="1" size="2" />
&nbsp;
<input type="submit" value="GO">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){
      echo 'DESCRIPTION: '.$row['DESCRIPTION'];
      }
```

has to be

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
  echo 'DESCRIPTION: '.$row['DESCRIPTION'];
  }
```

and

```
$result1=mysql_query($sql);
```

has to be

```
 $result1=mysql_query($sql1);
```

You might want to consider giving variabels a name more suited for the result that you will get.

This will not only make it easier to tell which will have what result, it will also be easier to pick up where you left off if you ever want to pick up a project that you haven't touched in a while or if someone else has ever to work with your code.

I'll end with some wise words that I had from a teacher a while ago.

'If you have a variable named beers' which represents an array of numbers, the result will always dissapoint you'

Answer (score 1):

You must change your while loop to

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
...
}
```

because, `$sql1` is just a string and not the result of the previous `mysql_query`.

You should consider switching to `mysqli` or `PDO`, because `mysql_*` functions are deprecated by now.

Comment: Thanks for informing me. I switched to PDO.